# Can I get import declarations in my own script file from a (CDN sourced) <script type="module">

Tags: javascript

If I have a `<script type="module">` in my html that comes from a CDN (and for which I know it contains exports), is it then possible to get the import declarations in a script file of my own?

i.e. in my html:

`<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@.....min.js"></script>`

in my own `.js` file

```
import {
    bla1,
    bl2 
} from ---
```

What comes in the place of the ---?

Comment: Just import `from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@.....min.js";`

Comment: Yeah, that is what I have know. Was hoping there would be a bit more elegant way by using a name or something. Problem is people can potentially change the ```<script>``` tag to include a local file but the .js file that I'm making is part of a library and can't be changed...